# Fixed-width layout with full-width footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I need to create a fixed 980px width page with full-width (liquid, fluid, wider than 980px) footer and horizontal menu. I hoped that simply putting them both outside of a fixed-width content div would do it but it does not work for the footer (only for the menu). The footer still shrinks to 980px width of the content. And when I go to the page and check HTML through Firebug I see that footer is magically **inside** a content div. Basically, whatever I put after the wrapper closing tag, gets sucked into the content div. But how??

Here's the html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header id="header"></header>
  <nav id="horizontal_menu"></nav>
  <div id="content">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
  <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">some text</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -80px;
}

#content, {
  width:980px;
  margin:auto;
 }

.footer, .push {
   height: 80px;
 }

#footer {
   background:#393939;
   color:#777;
   clear:both;
 }
```

(it's Rails app if it matters)

EDIT:
Turns out the problem is only on the frontpage. Other pages are doing fine.
"Yield" in content div depends on a page so here is frontpage.html.erb which is substituted for "yield":

```
<div style="color:#515151;font-size:14px;">
  <div id="navslides">
    <nav id="sidebar">
       some list  
     </nav>

    <div id="boxes">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="latest">
      <div class="frontarticle">
      <div class="frontarticle">
  </div>
  <div class="righties">
     <ul class="tabs" data-persist="true">
        <li><a href="#view1">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#view2">text</a></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="tabcontents">
        <div id="view1" style="min-height:200px;">text</div>
        <div id="view2" style="min-height:200px;">text</div>
</div>
  <div class="righties" style="margin-top:40px;margin-bottom:400px;">
    text
  <div>
```

Comment: What's in `<%= yield %>`? Just text? More HTML?

Comment: It's more HTML, I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not closing your div's correctly, with the additional HTML you posted, your page markup will look like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/TC4S5/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header id="header"></header>
  <nav id="horizontal_menu"></nav>
  <div id="content">
    <div style="color:#515151;font-size:14px;">
        <div id="navslides">
            <nav id="sidebar">some list</nav>
            <div id="boxes">
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="latest">
            <div class="frontarticle">
                <div class="frontarticle"></div>
                <div class="righties">
                    <ul class="tabs" data-persist="true">
                        <li><a href="#view1">text</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#view2">text</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tabcontents">
                        <div id="view1" style="min-height:200px;">text</div>
                        <div id="view2" style="min-height:200px;">text</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="righties" style="margin-top:40px;margin-bottom:400px;">text</div>
                </div>
                <div class="push"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">some text</div>
```

`latest` isn't closed, `content` isn't closed, and `wrapper` isn't closed. That div with `style="color:#515151;font-size:14px;"` isn't closed either.

The reason the footer is magically inside the content div is because it actually is! The content div was never closed. You need to take another look at your markup.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if I remove the entire `#content` style and just add the width to the `.wrapper`:

```
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -80px;
  width: 980px;
}
```

[See it running on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SsVur/).

Comment: Thank you but it's not helping in my case